# LocalStorage в произвольную локальную директорию

Tags: javascript, localstorage

Собственно вопрос. Можно ли сохранить данные  LocalStorage в произвольную директорию и выгрузить их оттуда после? 
Делаю локальную веб страницу и мне необходимо сохранить объект с настройками рядом с проектом.

Comment: вам нужно реализовать бекенд часть которая будет доступна через API. Напрямую браузер не имеет доступа к файловой системе из соображений безопастности.

Comment: а что значит в произвольную директорию?

Comment: Komdosh, по указанному пользователем пути

Comment: тогда вы хотите сохранить файл на компьютер? Или использовать LocalStorage который в браузере?

Comment: torokhkun, возможно ли без интернет подключения использовать api и на чем его написать?

Comment: Komdosh, я хочу реализовать локальный файл с объектом, который будет находится рядом с js файлом моего локального сайта и не будет зависеть от настроек браузера, т.е. его нельзя будет очистить, удалив допустим браузер.

Comment: тогда @torokhkun всё правильно написал, это не LocalStorage, вам нужен сервер, например на node, посмотрите в гугле как это делается, создайте API, который будет сохранять и загружать файл.

Comment: @Komdosh, а есть ли офлайн способ?

Comment: сервер не предполагает, что он будет запущен на удалённой машине, каждый может развернуть свой локально